# The detail function about epoll_insert

Tags: linux, io, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, epoll

The `epoll_insert` function is called by `sys_epoll_ctl`.

There are some key steps in `epoll_insert` function :

1. Initialize the poll table using the queue callback : `ep_ptable_queue_proc`
2. And it will call the `file->f_op->poll`
3. If the file is already "ready" , then we drop it inside the ready list

   ```
   /* If the file is already "ready" we drop it inside the ready list */
   if ((revents & event->events) && !ep_is_linked(&epi->rdllink)) {

       list_add_tail(&epi->rdllink, &ep->rdllist);

       /* Notify waiting tasks that events are available */
       if (waitqueue_active(&ep->wq))
           wake_up_locked(&ep->wq);
       if (waitqueue_active(&ep->poll_wait))
           pwake++;
   }
   ```

I don't understand why to check whether file is ready in `epoll_insert` function. Should we check it in `ep_poll_callback`  function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ep_poll_callback` is only called when the status of one of the file descriptors changes. If that were the only place that epoll descriptors were added to the read list, you could potentially miss events that occurred before you managed to add them to epoll. For instance, in a web server, you could miss a client's request if it was sent immediately after connecting.